# Unable to Insert CSV data in MongoDB using php

Tags: php, mongodb, csv

Problem: Succeeding rows are not inserted. Only the first row is inserted (see 1st comment)

### Read CSV file and then store each row as data in MongoDB using PHP

```
$connect = new MongoClient();

$collection = $connect->database->collection;

$csvfile= fopen("filename.csv","r");

$row = 1;

while (!feof ($csvfile) ) {   
   $data = (fgetcsv($csvfile));
   $col_length = count($data); 
   $row++; 
   for($col = 0; $col < $col_length; $col++) {
     $doc[] = $data[$col];
   }    
   $collection->batchInsert($doc);
   echo "Row : ".$row." inserted";
}

fclose($csvfile);
```

Comment: Only the first row is inserted.

Comment: $doc is not initialized. The loop appends $col_length times $data to $doc?

Comment: My mistake, declared  $doc[]=$data[$col];

Comment: [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) returns an array. Why did you iterate it again to assign in an array?
Please check the read data by using some log or print_r/echo.

Comment: trying to store each row as a document in a single Collection in MongoDB .Assuming each $doc[] will represent a row for a column ($data[$col]).